# React-Native, Firebase and some Reloads, login stops working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-native

I'm testing react-native (android) with firebase, and I did a small app to auth on firebase.

The problem is, when I hit R+R 3 or 4 times, firebase stops authenticate user.

In ./src/actions/login.js have a console.log that I put to try to debug.
When promisses (.then()) occur, I have another console.log(user), but when I reload the app 3 or 4 times the console.log(user) stop to appear. But the others two console.log (starting auth) and console.log(finish auth) works every time.

If I close Metro Bundler  and open again, the authentication process will working on the first time, second time, but if I reload app 3 or 4 times (sometimes needs a lot of R+R), authentication process will not occurs and I can't get error on .catch().

Someone are facing this problem or could help me?
Thanks.

Here is my code:

./src/config/app_config_firebase.js

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {
  FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
} from './constants';

const config = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const database = firebase.database();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

./src/actions/login.js

```js
import { auth } from '../config/app_config_firebase';

export const loginUser = () => {

    console.log('starting auth');
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword('user@user.com', '123456')
    .then((user) => console.log(user))
    .catch(erro => console.log(erro));
    console.log('finish auth');

}
```

./App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import { loginUser } from './src/actions/login';


export default class App extends Component {

  _autenticarUsuario() {
    loginUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Button 
            title='Login'
            onPress={() => this._autenticarUsuario()}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on your `loginUser` function

```
auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword('user@user.com', '123456')
.then((user) => console.log(user))
.catch(erro => console.log(erro));
console.log('finish auth');
```

it is worked for  me 
hope it'll help you...